# My div is stuck between other divs, wont go at the bottom

Tags: html, css

So my mission is to get the gray rectangle (`<div class="brand"> </div>`) to go automatic below the others, right now it's stuck between the header and my two other body divs. As I am a beginner I have no idea about how to fix this, i've searched a little and tried to add a `clear: both`, but that didn't solve my problem. Would love if someone out there can take a look at my code and see what's wrong. I'm sorry for no structure in my code.

**Thanks,Filip**

:D

**CODE (CSS FIRST, THEN HTML):**

```css
body{
background: white;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
padding-bottom: -1px;
}
.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
header{
  background: #fff;
}
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
header ::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav{
float: right;
padding-right: 230px;
}
nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 25px;

}
nav a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a:hover{
  color: red;
}
nav li:hover{
}
.fa-search{
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.fa-bars{
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

nav i:hover{
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}





.bild1{
  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 80px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 4;
  background-image: url('Img/KBA.jpg');
  background-position: 10% 30% ;
  background-size: 180%;

}

.bild2{
  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-left: 120px;
 z-index: 3;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #3D6BB8;

}

.entrytext{
float: right;
margin-right: 90px;
margin-top: 175px;
clear: both;


}
.entrytext>h1{
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 54px;
}

.entrytext>button{
border: none;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #38b272;
color: white;
padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
letter-spacing: 6px;
border-radius: 8px;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 17px;
text-align: left;
margin-top:   20px;
box-shadow: 20px 15px black;
}

.entrytext>button:hover{
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c12147;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
button:focus {outline:0;}

.fa-angle-right{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;

}


.entrytext>h2{
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 600;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.citygalleria{
  color: #CC2244;
}


.brand{
  height: 100px;
  weight: 400px;
  background-color: gray;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/908c2e5c96.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <title>Kungsmässan — Måste upplevas!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<header>

<div class="container">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Butiker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resturang & Café</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Utbyggnad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Öppetider</a></li>
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">

</div>
  <div class="bild1">
  </div>
  <div class="bild2">
  </div>
  <div class="entrytext">
    <h1>Sveriges bästa <br/> <span class="citygalleria">citygalleria.</span> Mitt  <br/> i Kungsbacka.</h1>
    <h2>35 000 KVADRATMETER OCH ÖVER 100 AFFÄRER!</h2>
    <button type="LÄS MER" name="button ">LÄS MER<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
  </div>

<div class="brand">

</div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Sorry for no structure ;D
//Filip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body{
   background: white;
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
   padding-bottom: -1px;
   }
   .container{
     width: 80%;
     margin: 0 auto;

   }
   header{
     background: #fff;
   }
   * {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   }
   header ::after {
     content: "";
     display: table;
     clear: both;
   }
   nav{
   float: right;
   padding-right: 230px;
   }
   nav li{
     display: inline-block;
     padding-left: 45px;
     padding-top: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
   }
   nav ul{
     list-style: none;
     display: inline-block;
     padding-top: 25px;

   }
   nav a {
     font-size: 12px;
     color: black;
     font-weight: 600;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   nav a:hover{
     color: red;
   }
   nav li:hover{
   }
   .fa-search{
     color: black;
     font-size: 14px;
     transform:scaleX(-1);
     margin-left: 50px;
   }
   .fa-bars{
     color: black;
     font-size: 14px;
     padding-left: 15px;
   }

   nav i:hover{
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
   }

   .package {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
   }
   .bild2 {
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #3D6BB8;
    float: left;
   }
   .entrytext {
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom:70px;
   }

   .entrytext>h1{
     font-weight: 800;
     font-style: normal;
     font-size: 54px;
   }

   .entrytext>button{
   border: none;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #38b272;
   color: white;
   padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
   letter-spacing: 6px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-size: 17px;
   text-align: left;
   margin-top:   20px;
   box-shadow: 20px 15px black;
   }

   .entrytext>button:hover{
     border: none;
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: #c12147;
     color: white;
     padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
     letter-spacing: 6px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     font-weight: 500;
     font-size: 17px;
     text-align: left;
     margin-top: 20px;
   }
   button:focus {outline:0;}

   .fa-angle-right{
     font-size: 20px;
     padding-left: 30px;

   }


   .entrytext>h2{
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 600;
   margin-top: 20px;
   }
   .citygalleria{
     color: #CC2244;
   }


   .brand {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    clear: both;
   }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/908c2e5c96.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
        <title>Kungsmässan — Måste upplevas!</title>
      </head>
      <body>

    <header>

    <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Butiker</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resturang & Café</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Utbyggnad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Öppetider</a></li>
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">

    </div>
      <div class="bild1">
      </div>
      <div class="package">
<div class="bild2">
      </div>
      <div class="entrytext">
        <h1>Sveriges bästa <br/> <span class="citygalleria">citygalleria.</span> Mitt  <br/> i Kungsbacka.</h1>
        <h2>35 000 KVADRATMETER OCH ÖVER 100 AFFÄRER!</h2>
        <button type="LÄS MER" name="button ">LÄS MER<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
      </div></div>

    <div class="brand">

    </div>



      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position its styling and add botom:0;

Comment: It's not working, when I add `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0;` it disappears and If I  change it to `position:relative` nothing happens, (it's still at the top between the nav and other divs).